# Variable.get() from Optionmenu not returning what I need to query mySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tkinter, optionmenu

forgive me for shoddy coding/description of the problem. I'm new to programming and this is my first question!
Anyways, I am building a simple inventory system with tkinter while using mySQL as a database. Currently, I am working on a feature that would allow a user to pick a department using an Optionmenu and then get all the items in that department. I have the items listed in one table and the departments listed in another with a FOREIGN KEY connecting the items table to the primary key (department_string) in the departments table.

My goal is to have mySQL deliver a list of departments and then to have the Optionmenu use that list for it's options. I then need to query the database with the department selected in the Optionmenu to find all the items in that department. My problem is that variable.get() from the Optionmenu returns parentheses and commas that is first received when I query the database the first time. This makes it so I cannot directly input the variable.get() into the string in the cursor. Here is the code:

```
        department_cursor.execute("SELECT department_string FROM departments")
        department_list = department_cursor.fetchall()

        variable = StringVar(search_window)
        variable.set(department_list[0])
        user_entry = OptionMenu(search_window, variable, *department_list)

        ***

        cursor_b.execute("SELECT item WHERE department_string = " + "'" + str(variable.get()) + "'")
```

I believe the problem is that variable.get() provides the special characters like the parentheses and comma that came from the original mySQL query. For example if the departments are HR, Warehouse, R&D then mySQL returns [('HR',), ('Warehouse',), ('R&D',)] this is then fed into the Option menu which then variable.get() spits out something like ('HR',), and so mySQL doesn't recognize this.

So far the only things I can think of is to use a for loop to delete all the special characters in what the Optionmenu returns or to hard code what the string for each department should be. Both seem suboptimal and although I'm pretty new to programming I think it's a little too much like rube goldberg machine.

Anyways, if you made it this far, thank you so much for reading this! Once again, I'm brand new to all of this so any help you can give me is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you verified that what you're putting into the optionmenu is what you think you're putting into the optionmenu? `.get()` will only return what is in the optionmenu, so if you're getting something wrong out, you're probably putting something wrong in.

Comment: Try `department_list = [rec[0] for rec in department_cursor.fetchall()]`.

Comment: acw1668 that works perfectly! Thank you very much! And thank you everybody who took the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

`.get()` is going to return whatever is in the optionmenu. If the values you put into the optionmenu have the undesirable characters, the value you get out will too.

The database call is going to return a list (rows) of lists (columns), and it doesn't look like you're taking that into account.